# Is it safe to fly over Iran?

Tags: air-travel, safety, event-based-effects

I am a pretty nervous flyer, and the recent events with Iran accidentally shooting down a passenger flight does not help. I am flying from Istanbul to Bangkok on Saturday with Turkish Airlines, and looking at the flight path a lot of the flight will be going over Iran. A lot of airlines (mostly American and European) are currently avoiding Iranian airspace, so why are a lot of airlines, like Turkish Airlines, still flying over Iran?

Comment: Is that the *standard* flight path or the *actual* flight path?

Comment: Looking on flightradar24.com the last couple of days, it is the actual flight path for TK58 and TK68.

Comment: I believe American and European airlines are being cautious. Weren't American airlines not flying over Iran for quite sometime now ? Turkish airlines and others assume that the danger over Iranian airspace is probably not that big.

Comment: Can't say I would feel great about flying over there myself (I will be in April) but if anything, it probably is the best time to be flying over Iran, as they will be being extra cautious to not make the same mistake that they already have!

Comment: The situation seems to be relatively settled for now but none of us can predict what Trump will do in the future!